# Removing taxonomy slug from URL but keeping post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

As the title says, I want to remove the taxonomy slug from URL. Instead, I want to keep the post type slug. For example: I have a post type called "Books" (`rewrite_slug = books`) and a taxonomy called "Genre" (`rewrite_slug = genre`) which includes "Science fiction", "Drama", "Comedy" etc.

Right now I have two options which work:

```
site.com/books/genre/comedy/
```

and

```
site.com/genre/comedy/
```

I want the url to look like:

```
site.com/books/comedy/
```

Is there a simple rewriting rule for this?

Comment: Is `comedy` a book or a genre? How will WordPress distinguish between the two?

Comment: @Milo - `comedy` is a term which belongs to the taxonomy `genre`. If I want to access a specific book I'd want this url: `site.com/books/comedy/some-comedy-book-name`.

Comment: @Milo - is it possible to remove the taxonomy slug from the title of the page? That is, instead of `SITENAME | Genre Comedy` to have `SITENAME | Comedy` or `SITENAME | Comedy Books`. Thank you.

Comment: Depending on how your theme handles those titles, you can [add a filter to `wp_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title) to set it to whatever you want.